# When appending multiple tspan child elements to an svg text object, is a new child element needed each time?

Tags: javascript, text, svg, tspan

I'm not sure of the best way to ask this.  I am wanting to append multiple tspan child elements to a single svg text object.  I have the following code.

```
var tspanElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
var majNote1 = document.getElementById('majNote1');

function myFunction() {
 for(i=1;i<6;i++){
   tspanElement.textContent=i;
   tspanElement.setAttribute("id",i);
   majNote1.appendChild(tspanElement);
 }   
}
```

When I run this, It appears that the tspan element is appended only once and not 5 times.  Is it possible to reuse the same tspan variable and append it 5 separate times?

You can see an example at http://codepen.io/cmgdesignstudios/pen/VePwog?editors=101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `appendChild` adds the element to the document. Subsequent calls of `appendChild` on the same element [only move](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) the element in the document tree. In your case, `tspanElement` is already the last child of `majNote1`, so `appendChild` does nothing.

So, yes, you should explicitly create each element. But you can and probably should reuse the variable: it is simply a named reference to the object, so you just move the `createElementNS` line to the top of the loop body, and the variable will refer to a different element on each iteration:

```
function myFunction() {
  var majNote1 = document.getElementById('majNote1');
  var tspanElement;
  for(i=1;i<6;i++){
    tspanElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
    tspanElement.textContent=i;
    tspanElement.setAttribute("id",i);
    majNote1.appendChild(tspanElement);
  }   
}
```